# Shutdown taking a lot of time

Tags: 11.10, performance, shutdown

Whenever I shutdown in my Ubuntu 11.10 box, the icons are changing to the default GNOME icons and it is taking a lot of time to shutdown. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently started having this. It was caused by Tomboy, the note taking program. For some reason it causes the shutdown to become very slow (I see the desktop for 10 or 15 seconds before it really shuts down).

I now no longer let Tomboy start at login and the problem is gone.

*added* - This is a known bug: [Bug #880290 Tomboy causing delay on logout or shutdown](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/880299)

Comment: looks it is the cause. I never noticed that the issue started to come up after I began to start Tomboy at startup. Thanks for the answer but I dont want to start Tomboy manually every time I login. Is this bug already reported ?

Comment: Looks like this has been reported: [Bug #880290 Tomboy causing delay on logout or shutdown](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/880299)

Answer (score 1):

it is not a proper answer but could be a kind of workout . 
1)never keep a cd/dvd in optical drive .
2)if you use wifi , disable it before shutdown .
3)close all programs and network connections , before shutdown.