# Long shutdown time with 11.10

Tags: 11.10, shutdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shutdown taking a lot of time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83224/shutdown-taking-a-lot-of-time)

I'm not sure if I'm the only one experiencing this, but I haven't been able to google anything. No matter what hardware I'm installing Oneiric on, right from pentium to core2duo but mostly laptops, the time it takes to shutdown has raised remarkable (maybe from 10 sec to 60 sec) from Natty to Oneiric (including Precise Alpha1). I'm taking about new clean installations from CD ISO's, an installation which hasn't been fiddled with at all.

Hitting "Esc" on it way down to get rid of the splash, I'm noticing that it hangs for a long time before writing something about "Starting modem-manager  [OK]" but then after a couple of secs more power off fine (and yes it says starting).

I have tried to "purge" the modem-manager, but that doesn't change much, so I'm afraid this isn't the guilty bugger then.

Anyone having same experience, or know what is causing this great change ?

Why does shutdown time matter then ? - because I not interested in destroying any harddisks by moving a box that is still reading/writing it.

- "Pisu" mentions [bug #875959](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/875959) in another ["shutdown" thread](https://askubuntu.com/q/83224/18612), maybe this could be the source - just remember in my case we're talking a virgin install of Ku or U-bunt here...
- Studying the above bug (and it duplicate), I've managed to cut 5-10 secs of by stopping network-manager before shutdown from GUI, so this at least could be part of the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/83224/18612

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I've spotted that one too (on the left menu since posting). I'm mostly using Kubuntu and I'm not experiencing quit that behavior (mentioned in that tread), when dual-boating a Ubuntu on the same box. In other words, it's the same behaviur, whether I use Ku og U-bunt.

Comment: "Pisu" mentions bug #875959 in another "shutdown" tread, maybe this could be the cource - just remember in my case we're talking a virgin install of Ku or U-bunt here...

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/875959

Comment: Studying the above bug (and it duplicate), I've managed to cut 5-10 secs  of by stopping network-manager before shutdown from GUI, so this at least could be part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a new install, this is probably a different issue, but I sometimes experience slow shutdowns when I have a Windows Share mounted with samba.  I'm not sure what happens to the share, but if I umount it first, the shutdowns are normal..

Comment: Agree on the dismounting of shares, but I often use browsing (not mounting) for accessing shared resources, (KDE) Dolphin/Konqueror has some fine features to make shortcuts to shares, and make them available to other apps too - But thanks anyway.